# What is the difference between using SDs away from the mean and SEs away from the expected value?

Tags: normal-distribution, mean, standard-deviation, expected-value, standard-error

I've always learned about the bell curve concept as having units in SDs away from the mean. For example, if the mean is 5 and the SD is 2, then the curve is centered around 5, and, for example, a data point would have a value of 1 if it were at the -2 position on the x-axis.

But a textbook I'm reading introduces a similar concept, except with the expected value and the standard error. The same exact example scenario as above could be described, except replacing "mean" with "expected value" and "standard deviation" with "standard error".

What is the difference between these two approaches? When is one used over the other? Or are they effectively the same?

Comment: Standard error has to do with inference about a value that you’ve estimated. A population does not have a standard error, but an estimate of some population parameter, such as mean or variance, could have a standard error.

Comment: @Dave Thank you! So which of these two ideas are being used in a typical bell curve? Since bell curves are about inference, is it standard error?

Comment: Both can come up with bell curves. Why do you say that bell curves are about inference, though? They can be...but they don't have to be.